# .net Maui Mapping between two models problem

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to consume a getall web api method and i expect showing all the data in my maui app.

I try to make auto mapping between my domain model and my modelVm I make the autMapper but when i try to consume an end point it handle this error:

> can not convert from your domain model to modelVM

In my gettall endpoint :

```cs
[RelayCommand]
async Task GetAllMatieresAsync()
{
    if (IsBusy)
         return;
    try
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        var matieres = await matiereService.GetAllMatieres();
        if (Matieres.Count != 0)
        {
             Matieres.Clear();
        }
        foreach (var matiere in matieres)
        {
             Matieres.Add(MatiereVM.FromMatiere(matiere));//Error line
        }
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
           await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error !!", $"Unable to get subjects:{e.Message}", "Ok");

     }
     finally
     {
         IsBusy = false;
         IsRefreshing = false;
     }
}
```

Comment: You should edit the question and add the code that does the mapping. Are you using AutoMapper? Are you doing the mapping manually?

Comment: I'm beginner with .net maui so for the case I'm using autoMapper i changed a little bit the logic so i add a  mapper profile class where i create my mapper inside her : CreateMap<Quiz, QuizVM>()
           .ForMember(dest => dest.QuizTitle, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.QuizTitle))
           .ForMember(dest => dest.QuizDescription, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.QuizDescription))
           .ForMember(dest => dest.Questions, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Questions)); 
            } and i also make the configuration of the Mapper